# Generating different signed urls with a loop (S3)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

im having an issue trying to create a list of urls for multipart upload to S3 using lamba, im trying to generate the URLs using a loop in the lambda function, but it only generates 1 and keeps returning that one across all the loop, so at the end i have an array of urls with the same url repeated, it doesnt happen if i call the generateSignedUrl() method multiple times in the code, i mean if instead of calling the for loop to loop 3 times, i use the generateSignedUrl() method 3 times it actually generates 3 different URLs, while the loop generates 1 repeated 3 times.

```
async function getSignedUrl(key){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      let params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key };
      s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, (err, url) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(url);
      })
});
}

async function process(items) {
  for (let item of items) {
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(item.fileName);
    item.url = signedUrl;
  }
  return items;
}


process(result).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Could you add your code here?

Comment: I did it sorry, i have tried a lot of things bit that is my actual code for that task.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop you are declaring *signedUrl* as a const.  This is why the value of the *signedUrl* is not changing for the items in the for loop and why it is working when you are calling your *getSignedURL* method explicitly.

Try changing *signedUrl* to a var.

Comment: Can you print out item.fileName inside the for loop to verify that the fileName is different for each item?  How do you call getSignedUrl when it does work?  When it does work, are you calling like this getSignedUrl(item[0].filename)?

Comment: `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, url) => {
            if(err) {
                callback(null, {err: err})
            }else {
                callback(null, { url: url }) 
            }
                
        })`
i simplified it and im doing the loop with the frontend with the same result.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with const or var.